# Fetching Data From A Server Only Once With Angular HTTP Client

Tags: angular

When using vanilla JS, I used to use promises to fetch data from an API to render it on the page. However, with Angular, I need to fetch the data in the component's `ngOnInit` method like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.shoppingService.getIngredients()
   .subscribe(ingredients => this.ingredients = ingredients)
}
```

OR
using `NgRx` actions and selectors.

That, no matter whether I use promises or observables, leads to the component sending a new request to the server whenever it gets instantiated.

I want to load the data only once because:

1. Sending multiple requests to the server to fetch the same data is not a good idea (I guess)
2. I store this data in my state so that the user can update it. Loading the data again overwrites the            modified data I have

Some people have suggested using the `shareReplay` operator from RxJS but this will overwrite my state if it has any updates. Others add a flag in their service like `wasFetched = false` and then they change it after the first load. But I just want to know, since this should be a simple thing to do, if there's a better solution.

Comment: Using `shareReplay` is literally as simple as adding one pipeable operator (given the same observable is returned each time). How much simpler could it be?

Comment: @BastianBräu
I know, and probably I should edit the last part. But using the `shareReplay` would overwrite my state, which might have some updates since I last fetched the data

Comment: alternatively check the state before making the call.  Something like if (!this.ingredients) {....make call to get ingredients...}

Comment: @BastianBräu I've mentioned that the data I get will be updated by the user. Calling the `get` method again (when navigating to the component again) will overwrite those updates

Comment: @pcalkins Usually, I usually initialize the data to an empty array. thus, `this.ingredients` will sadly evaluate to true.

Comment: should be initialized to state, no?

Comment: I don't know if NgRX has a best practice for this scnenario. But if you're using custom state management, you could build your observable in a way that it merges two sources. The API call and like an updateStateSubject$, so that when your state updates locally, you emit that patched state subject und your component will be up-to-date.

Comment: _I usually initialize the data to an empty array_ If that's the case, you could check the length of the array

Comment: @VilleKoo But I might have an empty array in other circumstances. For instance, the user can delete ingredients from their shopping list. Consequently, the fetched data could be an empty array, too. In this case the app will keep fetching data as the length is always 0

Comment: @BastianBräu Actually, I do something like this in my effects to tackle this. I use the `exhaustMap` operator which has a second argument called `index` that gets incremented every time a particular action is dispatched. So, I use this to track whether it's the first time the component dispatches this event. Therefore, I return the copy I have in the store if it's not the first time, otherwise, I fetch them from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe you can call the following code to fetch ingredients and automatically unsubscribe when the component is destroyed:

Declare a private Subject to manage the component's lifecycle

> private readonly destroyed$ = new Subject();

Call the shoppingService to get ingredients and subscribe to the observable

> this.shoppingService.getIngredients()
> .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
> .subscribe(ingredients => this.ingredients = ingredients);

When the component is destroyed, the subscription will be automatically unsubscribed

Comment: The problem is not about having the data up-to-data. It's about not making a call to the server every time the component gets instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a service for this and store the data or observable in the service. You can use DI to use the service in all the components you need. In the ngOnInit just check :

```
if(!this.shoppingService.myListArray)
{
this.shoppingService.getIngredients()
   .subscribe(ingredients => this.ingredients = ingredients);
}
else
{
this.ingredients = this.shoppingService.myListArray;
}
```

if it is `null` or `undefined`  you know you haven´t fetched any data before. Then you fetch the data and set it to your `myListArray` in the service and then to your `ingredients` in the component. Even if your user now deletes items from your array in the end the array is just empty but will never be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: That is what I used to do before, and it was great. With ngrx, it's quite different though. For instance, initializing my array to `null` will require a punch of `non-null assertion`s whenever I use it. I think I can solve this with typing my selectors properly. but thanks anyway

Comment: You could also disable the strict mode in angular.json if you dont want to do all the checks.